# Rest /me/items vs /users/1/items

Tags: rest, api

I'm building an API where a logged in user can see his or her information. The user is also able to change its information. Only the user should be able to see and change their own info. Is it better to use the following routes

```
/me
/me/items
```

or (with policies)

```
/users/1
/users/1/items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/users/1` is marginally better than `/me`, but in practice it probably doesn't matter at all.

At the high level, REST doesn't care about URI spellings at all.  General-purpose components treat the URI as opaque; only the origin server has any business trying to extract semantic information from the identifier.

From a design perspective, `/me` is somewhat vulnerable to the fact that you are combining two different concerns; "who is this resource about?" "who is allowed access?".  It happens that today "Bob" is the only person authorized to read the "Bob" resource, but there's no particular reason that those two ideas will always be coupled together.

From the perspective of REST, having the same resource identifier mean different things depending on other header information could make the caching of representations problematic, in that you force the caches to become a lot smarter about deciding when a representation can be re-used.

HTTP solves some of this problem via the Vary header, which allows the origin server to describe to general purpose components which parts of the HTTP request might change the correct representation to use.

But in practice, even that is irrelevant, because [HTTP doesn't permit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2) shared caches to store a response to a request with an Authorization header field.